# Stopping registration attempts on asterisk server from unknown ips

Tags: asterisk, voip, digital-ocean

Im new to Asterisk and have installed Asterisk 11 on a machine running in Digital Ocean. Since im learning asterisk i have disabled firewall using `sudo service iptables stop` . Now whenever i login to the asterisk console using `asterisk -rvvv` i see a lot of attempts to register from unknown ip as can be seen in the screenshot below. Can someone please guide me as to how can i stop this ?

Thank You.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjpMK.jpg)

Comment: Without a firewall you can't - this is what happens sadly - people will probe IP addresses then hammer away till they find a way in. You could have a look at https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page which is widely used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to fail2ban. Will check it out :)

Comment: no worries - I'll write it up as an answer so if you eventually use it then you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without some sort of firewall or banning program you can't really do what you want.

Asterisk will allow you to specify allowed hosts for remote connections, but this won't stop anyone and everyone hammering your server to see if they can find a way in.

You may want to have a look at [Fail2Ban](https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which is used widely across linux machines and appears to work quite well and should be able to offer you some protection while testing. In a production setup there is no reason you can't use both - you should note that fail2ban uses IPTables (from memory) so you may have to re-enable that for it to work - you will need to check any existing config (which you may need to remove)

Comment: Installed and configured fail2ban. The registration attempts from unknown ips seem to have stopped now. Thanks a lot !.

Comment: no worries - keep a close check on the logs though as they *will* be back from another source IP... Its a sadly common issue, not much is safe these days online unprotected :(

Answer (score 0):

Probably fail2ban + iptables are the best if the SIP clients are connecting from dynamic IP adresses, but there are ACLs in Asterisk, which can do static access control.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Asterisk 15.2 on Fedora 26
I'm using fail2ban to dynamically ban IPs working with firewalld.

```
# fail2ban-client -V
Fail2Ban v0.9.7
```

Fail2ban brings regex filters by default that work pretty well. If you need customize, you can use the ' .* ' to simplify log_prefixes into /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/XXXX.conf , for instant:

```
failregex = .* Registration from '[^']*' failed for '<HOST>' - IP Not Allowed by GF
```

I've made some customizations such as:

File: /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf:

```
ignoreip =      127.0.0.1/8
                1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2 YOUR-IP-ADDRESSES THAT NEVER MUST BE BANNED
                3.3.3.3 4.4.4.4

[asterisk]
enabled  = true
banaction = %(banaction_allports)s
action   = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="all", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s]
logpath  = /var/log/asterisk/messages
findtime = 7200
#bantime ->  3600 1h 36000 10h, 86400 1d, 864000 10d, 2592000 30d, 31104000 360d
bantime = 31104000
maxretry = 2
```

File: /etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-allports.conf

```
#gf
actionban =     <iptables> -I f2b-<name> 1 -s <ip> -j <blocktype> -m comment --comment "Banned <name> Attempts: <failures>"

actionunban = <iptables> -D f2b-<name> `iptables -nL f2b-<name> --line-numbers |grep <ip> | cut -d' ' -f1`
```

File: /etc/fail2ban/jail.d/00-firewalld.conf

```
[DEFAULT]
#banaction = firewallcmd-ipset
banaction = firewallcmd-allports
```

Reloading fail2band:

```
- fail2ban-client reload
```

Checking current bans:

```
- iptables -nL
```

My output looks like:

```
Chain f2b-asterisk (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  163.172.201.51       0.0.0.0/0            /* Banned: 2018-03-08 05:48:40 asterisk Origin: GB Attempts: 2 */
DROP       all  --  89.163.148.103       0.0.0.0/0            /* Banned: 2018-03-07 21:07:01 asterisk Origin: DE Attempts: 2 */
DROP       all  --  185.12.179.221       0.0.0.0/0            /* Banned: 2018-03-07 18:07:01 asterisk Origin: DE Attempts: 21 */
DROP       all  --  35.195.121.71        0.0.0.0/0            /* Banned: 2018-03-07 15:50:27 asterisk Origin: US Attempts: 4 */

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  85.93.20.92          0.0.0.0/0            /* Banned: 2018-02-27 19:21:12 sshd Origin: PL Attempts: 3 */
DROP       all  --  85.93.20.91          0.0.0.0/0            /* Banned: 2018-02-27 19:20:50 sshd Origin: PL Attempts: 3 */
```

Remembering activate the services, if it's needed change 'status' by 'enable' in the following commands

```
systemctl status fail2ban.service
systemctl status firewalld.service
```

Last important considerations: Unban IP and ALWAYS review the log

```
fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip x.x.x.x

tail -f /var/log/fail2ban.log
```

Best regards,